# Excel Chart names in Name Box

Tags: excel, vba

I am creatin multiple charts on  a single sheet. Lets say I have a sheet "Sheet 1" and on this sheet I am creating 10 charts with name from "chart 1" to "Chart 10". But the problem is when I click the name box,list of all the charts is not available in that name box.
 Can any one help me out how to do that through simple excel or excel VBA.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: I don't believe anything other than range names or the currently selected object is available in the "name box". The only alteration I have ever seen made to the name box is a width increase

In Xl2010 you can see all the charts using the Selection Pane
Home .... Editing .... Find & Select .... Selection Pane

**Original**
Something like this would give you the list

Did you want the ability to select a chart from the list and activate it, or just the list itself?

```
Sub GetCharts()
    Dim chr As ChartObject
    Dim strOut As String
    For Each chr In Sheets(1).ChartObjects
        strOut = strOut & chr.Name & vbNewLine
    Next
    If Len(strOut) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Chart Names are:" & vbNewLine & strOut
    Else
        MsgBox "No charts", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: yes I want the functionality to select them just as it happens in case of named ranges.

Comment: but this code will show the names in msg box.I want them in name box,the box just above "A1" cell in any sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The macro below outputs more information about the charts in a workbook and a worksheet than brettdj's.  The idea is to give you a fuller indication of the information that is available and how you access it.

However, I do not understand what you want to appear in the Name Box.

```
Sub Test1()

  Dim InxCO As Integer
  Dim InxWS As Integer

  For InxWS = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    With Sheets(InxWS)
      Debug.Print "Worksheet: " & .Name
      Debug.Print "  " & .ChartObjects.Count & " charts"
      For InxCO = 1 To .ChartObjects.Count
        With .ChartObjects(InxCO)
          Debug.Print "  Chart: " & .Name
          Debug.Print "    Location: " & .TopLeftCell.Address & " to " & _
                                         .BottomRightCell.Address
          If .Chart.HasTitle Then
            Debug.Print "    Title: " & .Chart.ChartTitle.Text
          Else
            Debug.Print "    Untitled"
          End If
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: As neha made clear below my initial post the question wanted to add the chart names to the name box so that the charts could be directly selected from the dropdown   .... but OI don't belive that this is possible. Also, the question didn't ask for detailed chart info - it was for a list of names

Comment: I agree, @brettdj, that neha did not ask for the detail I gave but I have had too many clients ask for what they think might be possible rather than what they want. If neha only wants a drop down list, a little macro with a shortcut key seems an easy solution. However, I have rarely seen charts with useful names; hence my showing how to access other properties, such as title, which might be more meaningful to a user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2007+, there is a **Selection and Visibility window** that you can activate.

To see this,

```
1) insert ANY shape on your sheet

2) **Format > Arrange > Selection Pane**
```

You can, at this point, right-click the Selection Pane icon and add it to your QAT. Using the icon on your QAT, means that the **Selection and Visibility window** can be activated any time, with or without shapes on a sheet.

Comment: But i want the names in Name box, Dont want to go to Selection Pane.

Comment: @Neha, I had earlier posted the Selection Pane proposal as a replacement for the Name box in my edited post. I don't think its possible to add them to the name box.